# Python - Criar variavel dinamica para o firebase

Tags: python, firebase, variáveis, pandas

Tenho um código que recebe de uma planilha o `CodProduto`, `Descrição` e `Quantidade` e, em seguida, os insere no banco de dados. Só que ele faz esse looping 1000x.

Como posso criar variáveis com esse `db.child` e fazer tudo de uma vez só ou em uma quantidade menor de vezes?

Código:

```py
while contador2 < npedido2.count():

  while logica1 == logica2:

  db.child("Pedidos").child(str(npedido2[contador2])).child("CodProduto").update({contador2:
codpedido[contador2]})

  db.child("Pedidos").child(str(npedido2[contador2])).child("Descrição").update({contador2: descricao[contador2]})

  db.child("Pedidos").child(str(npedido2[contador2])).child("Quantidade").update({contador2: str(quantidade[contador2])})

  contador2 = contador2 + + 1
```

Comment: Vai ficar mais fácil alguém te responder se o código acima for identado corretamente. Tente usar apóstrofo invertido triplo, em vez de identar pra frente (\`\`\` ) para demarcar o trecho de código. Lembre-se que em Python identação nao é um "acessório estético", e sim, define a estrutura do seu programa.

Answer (score 0):

@Giovane,

Se a biblioteca que você estiver usando for a `firebase`. Use algo como abaixo:

```
from firebase import firebase


firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('URL of Database', None)
data =  { 'Name': 'John Doe',
          'RollNo': 3,
          'Percentage': 70.02
          }
result = firebase.post('/python-example-f6d0b/Students/',data)
print(result)
```

Retirado [daqui](https://morioh.com/p/4dca3ded4cea)

No seu caso, contrua a variável `data` com o `CodProduto`, `Descrição` e `Quantidade`.

Vc também teria que acertar a `URL of Database` e a url do `post`

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

não conheço muito como funciona a api para python e não sei se é o realtime database ou o firestore.
no firestore, quando for realizar uma quantidade muito grande de registros e recomendado realizar gravações em lote no banco de dados. tem um limite de 500 gravações por lote.
leia mais em: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions%23batched-writes